# Initial chain sync crashed due to power outage - db-salvage fails. Can anything else be done?

Tags: synchronization

The initial chain sync crashed due to a power outage.

Now monerod fails to start.

2023-10-06 14:05:23.938 I Monero 'Fluorine Fermi' (v0.18.2.2-release)
2023-10-06 14:05:23.939 I Initializing cryptonote protocol...
2023-10-06 14:05:23.939 I Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
2023-10-06 14:05:23.940 I Initializing core...
2023-10-06 14:05:23.941 I Loading blockchain from folder E:\xxxxx\MONERO\lmdb ...
2023-10-06 14:05:23.966 E Failed to parse block from blob
2023-10-06 14:05:24.085 I Stopping cryptonote protocol...
2023-10-06 14:05:24.088 I Cryptonote protocol stopped successfully
2023-10-06 14:05:24.090 E Exception in main! Failed to parse block from blob retrieved from the db

--db-salvage --log-level=4 --data-dir "E:\xxxxxx\MONERO"

2023-10-06 13:53:36.425 T BlockchainLMDB::get_block_blob_from_height
2023-10-06 13:53:36.425 T BlockchainLMDB::height
2023-10-06 13:53:36.426 T BlockchainLMDB::get_block_blob_from_height
2023-10-06 13:53:36.426 E Failed to parse block from blob
2023-10-06 13:53:36.426 T BlockchainLMDB::block_rtxn_stop
2023-10-06 13:53:36.429 T Miner has received stop signal
2023-10-06 13:53:36.433 T Not mining - nothing to stop
2023-10-06 13:53:36.433 T Blockchain::deinit
2023-10-06 13:53:36.434 T Stopping blockchain read/write activity
2023-10-06 13:53:36.434 T BlockchainLMDB::close
2023-10-06 13:53:36.434 T BlockchainLMDB::sync
2023-10-06 13:53:36.777 T Local blockchain read/write activity stopped successfully
2023-10-06 13:53:36.778 T BlockchainLMDB::~BlockchainLMDB
2023-10-06 13:53:36.779 I Stopping cryptonote protocol...
2023-10-06 13:53:36.779 I Cryptonote protocol stopped successfully
2023-10-06 13:53:36.780 E Exception in main! Failed to parse block from blob retrieved from the db